# question about php mail function

Tags: php

what is smtp,smtp_port?and how can it get?

Comment: well, christmas had already past so you would have to wait to ask for it this upcoming christmas.

Comment: SMTP at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: A better question might be *why*.  Why can it get?  I can honestly answer "tree".

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Windows server, you need to specify the address (domain name och IP) to an sending e-mail server. On real operating systems PHP will always use your local Mail Transer Agent (MTA).

This is clearly explained in the PHP manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp

Also, this question is better asked on Serverfault.com

Comment: Something in your answer tells me you don't like Windows :D

Comment: Gordon ;-) It's just really frustrating to work with such unlogical  design choices.