# how can i send message?

Tags: php, email, server-configuration

I have programmed for mailing in php.but how can i send mail through local server?

Comment: Ask your question on Serverfault.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026089

Comment: http://thephpcode.blogspot.com/2009/03/setting-up-local-mail-smtp-pop3-imap.html

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem. You send email by using the PHP `mail()` function. If this is not working, show us the code you have come up with so far and tell us which parts are not working as expected. The way your question is phrased now provides little insight to what the issue is and it is too ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

A full-on SMTP server would be overkill for just mailing from a script.  SMTP is for clients connecting to the server and sending mail.

To send mail from a script, use sendmail or postfix

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at [php.net](http://se.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php) regarding mailing. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the server is already set up to have either SMTP and/or sendmail, then most likely what you are looking for is the [mail() function](http://php.net/mail).

Basic usage for that would be something like this:

```
mail( 'recipient@email.com', 'The subject', 'A short or long message' );
```

when sending a long message, use the [wordwrap() function](http://php.net/wordwrap), to ensure that the message is broken displayed properly by the client.

```
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
```

Of course, if this does not work, then you may need to contact your server administrator to make sure that everything is correctly setup to allow you to send email.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an SMTP server. You can use iis for this purpose.